# How do i load a yaml file programatically the same way as using @ConfiguationProperties?

Tags: javascript, spring, properties, spring-boot, yaml

Not sure if this is an issue or if i'm just not going at it the right way. My issue is that i'm trying to load YAML files in 2 ways. One way is via the @configurationProperties and specifying a location. This works great and the YAML gets loaded properly into my Java object.

PageDescriptor.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:config/page.yml")
public class PageDescriptor {
private HashMap pageConfigs;

public PageDescriptor() {

}

public HashMap<String, PageConfig> getPageConfigs() {
    return pageConfigs;
}

public void setPageConfigs(final HashMap<String, PageConfig> pageConfigs) {
    this.pageConfigs = pageConfigs;
}
```

PageConfig.java

```
public class PageConfig {
    private String baseUrl;
    private String configLocation;
    private String navDescriptorKey;
    private String defaultRoute;

    public PageConfig() {

    }

    public String getBaseUrl() {
        return baseUrl;
    }

    public void setBaseUrl(final String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    public String getDefaultRoute() {
        return defaultRoute;
    }

    public void setDefaultRoute(final String defaultRoute) {
        this.defaultRoute = defaultRoute;
    }

    public String getNavDescriptorKey() {
        return navDescriptorKey;
    }

    public void setNavDescriptorKey(final String navDescriptorKey) {
        this.navDescriptorKey = navDescriptorKey;
    }

    public String getConfigLocation() {
        return configLocation;
    }
}
```

Next i was trying to load other YAML files into the same object but via java code. I approached it like this.

code to test pulling the config:

```
final PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resourceResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    final Resource[] resources = resourceResolver.getResources("classpath*:com/**/page.yml");
    if (!((resources == null) || (resources.length == 0))) {
        for (final Resource resource : resources) {
            // final Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            // final InputStream in = resource.getInputStream();
            // final PageDescriptor componentPageDescriptor = yaml.loadAs(in, PageDescriptor.class);
            // in.close();
            final YamlConfigurationFactory<PageDescriptor> factory = new YamlConfigurationFactory<PageDescriptor>(
                    PageDescriptor.class);
            final Map<Class<?>, Map<String, String>> aliases = new HashMap<Class<?>, Map<String, String>>();
            // aliases.put(PageConfig.class, Collections.singletonMap("pageConfig", "pageConfig"));
            factory.setResource(resource);
            factory.setExceptionIfInvalid(true);
            factory.setPropertyAliases(aliases);
            // factory.setValidator(validator);
            factory.setMessageSource(new StaticMessageSource());
            factory.afterPropertiesSet();
            final PageDescriptor componentPageDescriptor = factory.getObject();
        }
    }
```

While this loads the componentPageDescriptor object as a PageDescriptor it does not load the HashMap correctly it instead does HashMap>. Is there an easy way to simulate how the @ConfigurationProperties works in loading the YAML files?

below is the YAML file

```
---
#pageDescriptors:
  pageConfigs:
    Home:
      baseUrl: ""
      configLocation: "/static/app/src/scripts/pages/home/config.js"
      navDescriptorKey: "Default"
      defaultRoute: ""
```

**UPDATE:
As a temporary solution I was able to convert the YAML to Object to JSON to PageDescriptor and it works as expected.**

```
    final PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resourceResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    final Resource[] resources = resourceResolver
            .getResources("classpath*:com/**/page.yml");

    if (!((resources == null) || (resources.length == 0))) {
        for (final Resource resource : resources) {
            final Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
            final Object map = yaml.load(resource.getInputStream());
            final ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer();
            final String componentPageDescriptorString = ow.writeValueAsString(map);
            final PageDescriptor componentPageDescriptor = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(componentPageDescriptorString, PageDescriptor.class);
            pageDescriptor.merge(componentPageDescriptor);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You haven't shown all of the code that's involved, and the code that you have shown contains syntax errors. It'll be easier for people to help you if you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I've updated the code in the question to be more complete.  if there is still more you need please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution that is not the best but does the job.  I was able to convert the YAML to Object to JSON to PageDescriptor and it works as expected.

```
final PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resourceResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
final Resource[] resources = resourceResolver
        .getResources("classpath*:com/**/page.yml");

if (!((resources == null) || (resources.length == 0))) {
    for (final Resource resource : resources) {
        final Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
        final Object map = yaml.load(resource.getInputStream());
        final ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer();
        final String componentPageDescriptorString = ow.writeValueAsString(map);
        final PageDescriptor componentPageDescriptor = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(componentPageDescriptorString, PageDescriptor.class);
        pageDescriptor.merge(componentPageDescriptor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem would be to convert YAML first to a map using objectMapper and then convert that map to .properties file.

> Convert it to map

```
Map<String, Object> configMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

File yamlFile = new File(yamlLocation);

Yaml yaml = new Yaml();

InputStream input = new FileInputStream(yamlFile);

configMap = (Map<String, Object>) yaml.load(input);
```

Now using this map of map you can easily map it to .properties file using your custom logic.

You can also use this map in ur code for reading properties.